# Is it possible to show animation in uwp toast notification?

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to understand if it's possible to show a countdown timer for example or some sort of animation or anything dynamic in toast notification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this article from Microsoft

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/toast-progress-bar

This shows how to add a progress bar to a Toast Notification in a UWP app.

First you create your Toast Notification with a specific tag

```
using Windows.UI.Notifications;
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications;

public void SendUpdatableToastWithProgress()
{
    // Define a tag (and optionally a group) to uniquely identify the notification, in order update the notification data later;
    string tag = "weekly-playlist";
    string group = "downloads";

    // Construct the toast content with data bound fields
    var content = new ToastContent()
    {
        Visual = new ToastVisual()
        {
            BindingGeneric = new ToastBindingGeneric()
            {
                Children =
                {
                    new AdaptiveText()
                    {
                        Text = "Downloading your weekly playlist..."
                    },

                    new AdaptiveProgressBar()
                    {
                        Title = "Weekly playlist",
                        Value = new BindableProgressBarValue("progressValue"),
                        ValueStringOverride = new BindableString("progressValueString"),
                        Status = new BindableString("progressStatus")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    // Generate the toast notification
    var toast = new ToastNotification(content.GetXml());

    // Assign the tag and group
    toast.Tag = tag;
    toast.Group = group;

    // Assign initial NotificationData values
    // Values must be of type string
    toast.Data = new NotificationData();
    toast.Data.Values["progressValue"] = "0.6";
    toast.Data.Values["progressValueString"] = "15/26 songs";
    toast.Data.Values["progressStatus"] = "Downloading...";

    // Provide sequence number to prevent out-of-order updates, or assign 0 to indicate "always update"
    toast.Data.SequenceNumber = 1;

    // Show the toast notification to the user
    ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
}
```

Then you can use that tag to update the Toast Notification

```
using Windows.UI.Notifications;

public void UpdateProgress()
{
    // Construct a NotificationData object;
    string tag = "weekly-playlist";
    string group = "downloads";

    // Create NotificationData and make sure the sequence number is incremented
    // since last update, or assign 0 for updating regardless of order
    var data = new NotificationData
    {
        SequenceNumber = 2
    };

    // Assign new values
    // Note that you only need to assign values that changed. In this example
    // we don't assign progressStatus since we don't need to change it
    data.Values["progressValue"] = "0.7";
    data.Values["progressValueString"] = "18/26 songs";

    // Update the existing notification's data by using tag/group
    ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Update(data, tag, group);
}
```

Comment: what is 'data'?

Comment: `data` is a Windows.UI.Notifications.NotificationData object

Comment: @Matt, any chance you know how this can be build on a Windows Server 2016? I am getting 'ToastNotification' does not contain a definition for 'Data' as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55899493/toastnotification-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-data-on-windows-server-2)

Comment: @ToreØstergaard I am not sure. Looking around it looks like Windows 2016 has some issues with UWP. Quick Question. Do you have the Desktop Experience installed on Windows 2016 as well as all the latest upgrades / windows updates?

Comment: @Matt Desktop Experience is installed and the server is reasonably up-to-date. Windows.UI.dll seem to be following the server build regardless of update level and installed Windows SDK.

Comment: @ToreØstergaard What if you explicitly include the Windows.UI.dll in a lib folder in your project and update your project references to use the included dll instead of relying on Windows Server 2016 to resolve the proper dll?

Comment: I was hoping to avoid this as it seems that these DLLs are not available through a NuGet package.

Comment: As far as I can tell Windows Server 2016 does not support this at this notification object at this moment. You can try Windows Server 2019, but I don't know if it will work or not. I would only include the DLL with your source for the build process for the server. I would not package it with the final build of the app. If you are using something like Azure DevOps or something similar you could try and build this on a Windows 10 target machine.